# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(4x)}$ without using L'Hopital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(4x)}$  without using L'Hopital's rule. I've managed to get $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \cdot \frac{3x}{\sin(4x)} = 1 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x}{\sin(4x)}$ but can't figure out how to evaluate that limit.

Comment: Maybe, as $x$ approaches zero, use only the first term of the Taylor series expansion for each $\sin()$?

Comment: Hint: For $x \ne 0,$ note that $\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(4x)}=\frac{\sin(3x)/x}{\sin(4x)/x}.$ Now, recall the well-known limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$ Could it be useful for evaluating your limit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had the right idea, but you needed to apply this idea twice. Consider: $$\frac{\sin3x}{\sin4x}=\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\cdot\frac{4x}{\sin4x}\cdot\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: (+1) It would be a pitty not to use $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1.$ For the OP: this ubiquitous rule can be proved with L'Hopital, but easily without it: e.g. it is equal (by definition of the derivative) to $\sin'(0)=\cos0=1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval In order to show $\sin'(0)=1$ you need the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}{\sin x\over x}=1$  beforehand.

Comment: Yes, or other way round. It depends on how $\sin$ is defined.

Answer (score 5):

The application of the  limit $\lim_{x\to 0}{\sin x\over x}=1$ can be avoided. The solution below makes use of  the continuity of the cosine function at $0$ and trigonometry formulas.  Moreover  the units of measure for angles are not essential.
By the way, the continuity of the cosine function at $0$ follows easily from the symmetry $\cos(-x)=\cos x$ and an elementary analysis of the right triangle.

We have
$$\sin 3x=\sin(x+2x)=\sin x\cos 2x+\cos x \sin 2x\\
=\sin x\cos 2x +2\cos^2x\sin x =\sin x(\cos 2x+2\cos^2x) $$
Also
$$\sin 4x=2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=4\sin x\cos x\cos 2x$$
Therefore
$${\sin 3x\over \sin 4x}={\cos 2x+2\cos^2x\over 4\cos x\cos 2x}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} {3\over 4}$$
The method is painful for coefficients larger than $3$ and $4.$ Then one can rely on  formulas with complex numbers
$$\sin nx={e^{inx}-e^{-inx}\over 2i},\quad \cos nx={e^{inx}+e^{-inx}\over 2}$$

Comment: (+1) for avoiding the limit of the sinc function.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks!